# Error running Samba share of fuse mount

Tags: samba, redhat-enterprise-linux, fuse

I have created a fuse directory, and start it like this: `./myfuse /home/shared -o allow_other -o umask=022 -o nonempty -d`

I can access it like this: `ls -la /home/shared` and it works fine.

Ok, turn that off for a second.

I have a samba-share defined as:

```
[root@cboardman-rh1 /]# testparm /etc/samba/smb.conf 
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf 
rlimit_max: rlimit_max (1024) below minimum Windows limit (16384) 
Processing section "[shared]" 
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE 
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

[global]
            workgroup = MYWORKGROUP
            server string = Samba Server Version %v
            security = SHARE
            guest account = samba-user
            lanman auth = Yes
            client lanman auth = Yes
            log level = 5
            log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
            max log size = 50
            wins support = Yes
[shared]
            comment = Sharing for everyone
            path = /home/shared
            guest only = Yes
            guest ok = Yes
```

Start up samba, and I can `smbclient //cboardman-rh1/shared` and connect no problems.

Here's the question:  When I put the two together, I get trouble.

Specifically, when I do an `ls` from smbclient, I get

```
smb: \> ls
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*

                40960 blocks of size 512. 1 blocks available1
```

and fuse starts looking "/myfuse" instead of "/".   `ls /home/shared` (hitting just fuse) has fuse looking for "/", as desired.  Even adding a hack in my fuse code to translate "/myfuse" to "/", I get the same error code.

What is samba doing?  I'm not seeing anything helpful in the logs.  Any ideas?

I am on a RHEL server with SELinux and iptables disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1:  Make sure it works with the given examples.

Step 2:  Make sure your fuse code doesn't have any errors in it.  Including very subtle ones that may get ignored by a simple `ls` on a mounted fuse directory alone.

Comment: Awesome that you figured out what was wrong. Any chance you could be a bit more descriptive about what exactly the problem and solution were?

Comment: I don't know for caseyboardman, but I had the same problem and solved it after reading that answer here.  In my case the samba server tried to get the attributes of something nonsensical like "/path/to/*" (with a verbatim asterisk).  For that my getattr() raised a Python exception instead of returning `-errno.ENOENT`.  After consulting the fuse's log file, I found that out very quickly and after correcting it, I got my fuse running via samba.

Answer (score 2):

I used a fuse based script and i solved a similar SMB problem adding `-o allow_other,nonempty` to fuse args.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks, `allow_other` was enough for me